# Проблема с реализацией двух стеков на СИ

Tags: c, стек

Надо создать два стека и вывести их. Такая проблема. Когда я ввожу 3 элемента стека,все окей. Когда я ввожу 5 и больше вершина первого становиться такой же как начальный второго. К примеру: Первый стек : [1,2,3,4,5] Второй стек [6,7,8,9,10]
После функции push для второго,первый стек становиться таким: [1,2,3,4,6]. В чем может быть проблема?
код:

```html
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct stack {
    int numbers[15];
    int topIndex;
};
struct stack *top,*firstStack,*secondStack,*firstBuffer,*secondBuffer;
void push(struct stack *top,int f);
void init(struct stack *top);
void show(struct stack *top);
int isEmpty(struct stack *top);
int pop(struct stack *top);
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n,inf,i,temp,secondInf,rem;
    firstStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
    secondStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
    firstBuffer=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
    secondBuffer=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
    init(firstStack);
    init(secondStack);
    init(firstBuffer);
    init(secondBuffer);
    printf("Введіть кільіксть елементів обох стеків:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Введіть перший стек:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Введіть %d елемент\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&inf);
        push(firstStack,inf);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Введіть %d елемент\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&secondInf);
        push(secondStack,secondInf);
    }
    show(firstStack);
    return 0;
}
int pop(struct stack *top)
{
    int element;
    if(top->topIndex>=0)
    {
        element=top->numbers[top->topIndex];
        top->topIndex--;
        return element;
    } else
    {
        printf("stack is empty");
        return 0;
    }
}
void init(struct stack *top)
{
    top->topIndex=-1;
}
void push(struct stack *top,int f)
{
    if(top->topIndex<15)
    {
        top->topIndex++;
        top->numbers[top->topIndex]=f;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("stack is full");
    }
}

void show(struct stack *top)
{
    int i;
    i=top->topIndex;
    if(i==-1)
        return;
    do{
        printf("%d\n",top->numbers[i]);
        i--;
    }while(i>=0);
}
int isEmpty(struct stack *top)
{
    if(top->topIndex==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, данные предложения выделения памяти

```
firstStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
                                                    ^^^
secondStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
                                                    ^^^
```

некорректные.

Должно быть

```
firstStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack ));
secondStack=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack ));
```

Также не ясен смысл этих предложений

```
firstBuffer=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
secondBuffer=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack*));
```

так как неизвестно, где и с какой целью эти переменные, `firstBuffer` и `secondBuffer`, используются.

Метод push обращается за границу массива `numbers`, объявленного в структуре.

```
void push(struct stack *top,int f)
{
    if(top->topIndex<15)
    {
        top->topIndex++;
        top->numbers[top->topIndex]=f;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("stack is full");
    }
}
```

Например, если текущее значение переменной `topIndex` равно `14`, то в `if` предложении эта переменная инкрементируется `top->topIndex++;`, становясь равной `15`, а затем по этому индексу записывается значение, в то время как допустимый диапазон индексов для массива, объявленного как

```
int numbers[15];
```

это `0-14`.

Вам по крайней мере следует изменить условие следующим образом

```
    if ( top->topIndex + 1 < 15 )
```

Имейте в виду, что заголовок `<malloc.h>` является не стандартным заголовком. Вместо него используйте заголовок `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Вы мне очень помогли.